# Representation of linear mappings as matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (2nd edition), and I don't understand how a matrix is determined from a linear map. On page 48, he writes that $Tv_k$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the $w$'s, so that

$$Tv_k = a_{1,k}w_1 + ... + a_{m,k}w_m,$$

where $(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $(w_1,...,w_m)$ are bases, $a_{j,k}$ is a matrix entry, and $T$ is a linear map. This mostly makes sense for me. But the linear map should determine a matrix that behaves the same way as the map, so that $Tx = Ax$. But the equation from the book seems to imply that $Tv = Aw$, and I don't get how these are connected. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Can you include more? Which equation from the book seems to imply that $Tv  =Aw$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The same linear map has different matrices in different coordinates

Comment: @ArcticChar if you have the book, it's equation 3.8

Comment: I don't, sorry. Is it possible that you include that in your post? That help other understand your doubt.

Comment: @ArcticChar done

Answer (score 1):

*"But the linear map should determine a matrix that behaves the same way as the map, so that $Tx=Ax$."*

What if you have a linear transformation that takes a polynomial? Does it make sense to say that $Tp = Ap$ for some matrix $A$?

To specify the way in which the matrix of a linear transformation behaves as the linear transformation, let me fix some notation.

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces. Choose a basis $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ for $V$, which we will call $\mathcal{B}$, and a basis $w_{1}, \ldots, w_{m}$ for $W$, which we will call $\mathcal{E}$. I will denote the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ by $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{E}}$.

For $v$ in $V$, I will denote by $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ its coordinates with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, written as a column vector. So if

$$ v = \alpha_{1}v_{1} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}v_{n} ,$$
then
$$ [v]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix}
           \alpha_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           \alpha_{n}
         \end{pmatrix}.
   $$

Similarly, if

$$ Tv = \beta_{1}w_{1} + \ldots + \beta_{m}w_{m}, $$

we write

$$ [Tv]_{\mathcal{E}} = \begin{pmatrix}
           \beta_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           \beta_{m}
         \end{pmatrix}.
   $$

Now suppose you were only given the bases $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{E}$ and the matrix $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{E}}$. Would you still be able to know $Tv$ for any $v \in V$? Well, of course! The matrix contains all the relevant information about $T$. We can get the coordinates of $Tv$ (and thus $Tv$) via matrix multiplication:

> **Proposition.** Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces with bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{E}$, respectively, and let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. Then, for any $v \in V$,
> $$ [T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{E}} [v]_{\mathcal{B}} = [Tv]_{\mathcal{E}}. $$

Notice that $T$ takes a vector $v \in V$, but the matrix of $T$ acts on the coordinates of $v$.

Since you're reading Axler's LADR, this is result 3.65 in the 3rd edition.

As a particular case of the previous result, consider a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ and let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$. It can be verified that
$$ Tx  = Ax$$
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. This seems to be the case you had in mind.